# Internet Explorer 9 Returns Null For Hidden Element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a javascript block which works before submitting a form. It works well at internet explorer 8. Here's my code:

```
if(document.getElementById("Element1")){
      document.getElementById("Element2").value = document.getElementById("Element1").value;
}
```

And element:

```
<input type="hidden" name ="Element2"/>
```

Internet Explorer 8 returns an object for `document.getElementById("Element2")` and it shows `document.getElementById("Element2").value` as "". But IE 9 returns `null` for `getElementById` method so I cannot access the value.

I see that IE9 did some changes about getting element, how do I solve this problem? The page contains `Element2` so I'm waiting to access its value by `getElementById` method. What's new at IE9?

Comment: is this in a domready state?

Comment: You haven't specified `id` attribute in your `HTML`

Comment: Yes, dom is ready. User is interacting with page, filling some inputs then we're submitting the form. As I said, IE8 returns object. IE9 has this problem.

Comment: Салман I will try to use id. Actually, I never think about id because it works at ie8. But It may cause problem at some browsers like this situation.

Comment: Салман Can you post it as answer? I tried this solution and it works now, I want to check it as answer. Thanks.